IRS Swaps market
I would like to understand who are the major actors in the IRS Swap market and what's the major reason of the volume traded for a certain tenor.
I am not able to find any of this information that describe this. For example 30Y Swaps are mostly traded by Insurance companies to hedge IR risks, short term swaps ...
So if someone has a good understanding of the market, the way it behave, who are the major actors, how can the majority of the flow can be explained, I would be extremely interested to learn about that because I can't find anything on the internet.

Your are right, it is mostly big Banks and (at the longer end) Insurance Companies that trade IRS. Some Hedge Funds too, that want to speculate on i.r..

@nbbo2 but do you know if it is possible to quantify in terms of % of volume traded? Like for example 40% of 30y swaps are traded by Insurance companies, HF mostly trade curves/butterflies on IR Swaps?  I would like to get that more precise understanding about that market...

@user68819 Very interesting!  Would you say it is the same for the UST? Like the flow for this product is the same as the one for IR swaps.

@user68819 Ok I see. Do you think you can answer this post by explaining what you said on SWAPS an also add something on the UST part? and I'll accept it, thx!

IRS:
Short end: macro , hedge funds, corporates to hedge loans etc. Banks maybe swapping mortgage flows.
Medium term is usually corporates swapping issuance, hedge funds rv, government issuance (although this can be spread all over and depends on their preferences etc).
Long end, pension funds, hedge funds, supras.
NB: Hedge funds tend to be active across the curve, and tend to appear as soon as an opportunity occurs, due to dislocation etc. The others are all really there to utilise swaps as a hedge or a method to convert cash flows floating to fixed or vice versa
UST:
Hedge funds again are active all over especially via basis/ASW positions. The US Tsy is also conducting buy backs now (which I think are across the curve).
Short End: MMF (bills), Foreign investors (I hear this is picking up again)
Medium term: AMs, Foreign Investors, Treasurers
Long end: Mortgage hedging, Pension Funds (P strips)
This is by no means exhaustive but should give you a flavour as to who is interested in what.
